# Refreshing css after adding element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problem loading custom css (twitter bootstrap) on radio input when I try to add that element using jQuery.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

When I refresh the page the css of the radio input is loaded (next to the green arrow) but when I click to Add new sequence.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('#btn_addseq').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var newitem = 'some tags' +
                            '<input type="radio" name="is_default" value="new_' + size + '"> Default</input>' +
                            'some tags' ;
            $("#list_sequences").append(newitem);
        };
```

**Edit:**
My html for the working one:

```
<label class="mt-radio mt-radio-line" style="margin-top: 6px">
<input type="radio"
name="is_default" value="old_{{ $sequence->id }}" {{ $sequence->is_default ? 'checked' : '' }}>
Default
```

What I see in inspection:
[image]

And this is the code of the item I'm trying to add:

```
var newitem = '<div class="col-md-4">' +
                    '<div class="mt-radio-list">' +
                    '<label class="mt-radio mt-radio-line" style="margin-top: 6px">' +
                    '<input type="radio" name="is_default" value="new_' + size + '"> Default</input>' +
                    '</label>'+
                    '<a class="delete_new_seq" data-id="' + size + '"><i class="fa fa-remove" style="color: red;cursor: pointer;"></i> </a>'
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' ;
```

Comment: If you look in the element inspector, what do the working radios look like vs the broken one?

Comment: This has nothing to do with "refreshing" css, and everything to do with actually applying the correct style to your dynamically added element(s)

Comment: @Jamiec I added the same tags as the working ones, I followed the documentation of twitter bootstrap

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using a custom bootstrap theme bought from themeforest.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules that govern what an element looks like rely on a particular structure of HTML, in this case it looks like the css rules you use rely on either

1. The radio being inside a `<div class="radio">` element. or;
2. The radio being inside a `<label class="mt-radio mt-radio-line">` element.

(My guess would be the former, however its hard to know for sure without seeing all your css)

Comment: It was relying on the former one :)  This was helpful to show the right css then I added some jQuery tweak to make it work:
`$("input[type='radio']").parent('span').removeClass('active checked');
                $(this).parent('span').addClass('active checked');`

Answer (score 1):

Your new control doesn't have the class specified. Add the class property to the tags like this:

```
    var newitem = 'some tags' +
                    '<input type="radio" name="is_default" class="----" value="new_' + size + '"> Default</input>' +
                    'some tags' ;
```

Comment: Also remember that any div around the other controls might change the placement. So that's something else you need to pay attention to!